# batch script to recursively loop sub-directories and find missing files in 2 folders

Tags: batch-file, compare, dos, directory

I would like to compare recursively 2 folders and find missing files in them. I am using for loop to compare 2 folders but not able to search sub folders. Can somebody help?

Here is the code that I tried,

```
@echo off
if "%2" == "" GOTO Usage

cd /D %1
if errorlevel 1 goto usage

for %%x in (*.*) do if NOT exist %2\%%x echo missing %2\%%x
cd /D %2
for %%x in (*.*) do if NOT exist %1\%%x echo missing %1\%%x

goto end

:usage
echo Usage %0 dir1 dir2
echo where dir1 and dir2 are full paths
:end
```

Comment: Maybe we can help if you would provide some code....

Comment: Please use the edit function and put the code in your question. Code in the comment box is unreadable. Thanks.

Comment: Added code in the question..i will try your code..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, for explanation see comments in the code:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "folder1=this"
SET "folder2=that"

REM delete variables
FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set "$"') DO SET "%%a="

REM scanning folder1
FOR /r "%folder1%" %%a IN (*) DO SET "$%%~nxa=%%~a"

REM compare with folder2
FOR /r "%folder2%" %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED $%%~nxa ECHO missing IN %folder1%: %%a
)

REM delete variables
FOR /f "delims==" %%a IN ('set "$"') DO SET "%%a="

REM scanning folder2
FOR /r "%folder2%" %%a IN (*) DO SET "$%%~nxa=%%~a"

REM compare with folder1
FOR /r "%folder1%" %%a IN (*) DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED $%%~nxa ECHO missing IN %folder2%: %%a
)

ECHO Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
XCOPY /l /y /d "%~1\*" "%~2\*"|FIND "\"
XCOPY /l /y /d "%~2\*" "%~1\*"|FIND "\"
GOTO :EOF
```

Not *strictly* listing the files that are in one directory but not in the other; lists those and also those that exist in both but have a different timestamp.

Add `/s` to the `XCOPY` options to scan subdirectories also.